# How to eager join further tables after joining a collection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to do eager joins on tables after eagerly joining autogenerated relations from automap.

I'm working with a database with plenty many-to-many relations and I want to do big joins  to get a lot of information out neatly using these.

So far I've used the joinedload on the autogenerated collections, which has worked fine. The problem comes when I want to eagerly join further tables.

This would not be an issue before closing/commiting the session (Using lazy joins), but I want all information to be queried in one query.

I tried setting up a minimal example describing what I want to do.
There's a Parent class with a many-to-many relation to the Child class.
(This relation is created by automap as child_collection)

```py
query = session.query(Parent)
query = query.options(joinedload(Parent.Child_collection))
```

A third table, School has a many-to-one relation with the Child class.
Heres how I would think it should be done:

```py
query = query.options(joinedload(Parent.Child_collection.School)
```

But this gives:

```
Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Parent.Child_collection has an attribute 'School'
```

I want to be able to do the following after joining:

```py
for Child in Parent.Child_collection :
    print (Child.School.name)
```

The only alternative solution I've found would be to query on all the tables, but then I'd get one entry per Child, instead of one per Parent.

Any help/input is much appreciated